# symantec Backup Exec 2010 vs 2012

Tags: backupexec, symantec

I have a work group of 30+ computers and would like to backup to a Buffalo NAS. I don't want to buy agents for each computer's but to install just the administrator console on one machine and run backups to the NAS Storage.

I have decided to go with Symantec Backup Exec, not sure which version I should go for 2010 or 2012?

I have learned Backup Exec 2012 doesn't allow to add network computers without agent running on them, which makes me to think Backup Exec 2010 will be the best choice? Can someone please suggest the best solution for my scenario ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to upgrade from BE 2010 to BE 2012. I also ran the Desktop/Laptop option on my BE server. BE 2012 doesn't allow this anymore and requires you to purchase a separate product called Symantec Desktop Laptop 7.0.
Apparently I have to either uninstall the Desktop/Laptop Option on my BE2010 Server in order to upgrade to BE2012, or else migrate to the newer Symantec Desktop LAptop 7.0 before I try to upgrade to Be2012.
Hope this info helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 2010 will require a Desktop/Laptop agent if you want automated backups.  2012 is also likely the only shipping version unless someone has product on the shelf.  I would go with latest